# Representation of multiple qubit matrices in Dirac notation

Tags: gate-synthesis, matrix-representation

Imagine one wants to represent the *and* function for any number of qubits in Dirac notation. The *and* gate flips the target qubit if all the control qubits are in state 1. This is its matrix representation :
$$\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

It can be decomposed into two parts :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \otimes I =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \otimes I-
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \otimes I
= (I-|1\cdots1\rangle\langle1\cdots1| ) \otimes I
\tag{1}$$
and
$$\begin {bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \otimes X =
|1\cdots1\rangle\langle1\cdots1| \otimes X
\tag{2}$$
So combining (1) and (2), we get : $$U_{and} = (I-|1\cdots1\rangle\langle1\cdots1| ) \otimes I + |1\cdots1\rangle\langle1\cdots1| \otimes X$$

This is still pretty easy to see, the example complicates a lot when we have an *or* gate : $$U_{or} = U_{or} = |0...0\rangle\langle 0...0|\otimes I + \big(I - |0...0\rangle\langle 0...0|\big) \otimes X$$ which applies the X gate on the target qubit if there is at least 1 control qubits in the $|1\rangle$ state.

My question is : is there any way to see these transformations in Dirac notation to use them in a program ? To gain some intuition on the decomposition.

Comment: Is there any point to this decomposition? the (1-|1...1><1...1|) and (1-|0...0><0...0|) terms arent unitary so there is no advantage from an implementation standpoint

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. You are already writing the matrices in braket notation here

Comment: I know this question is a bit hard to ask, but I want to know if there is any use in decomposing a gate in such a way, and furthermore, if there is a method for decomposing a gate in such a way.

Comment: However, I answered my questions already myself, should I close it, or answer it myself ?